# How to dismiss the keyboard upon tapping on my message collection view?

Tags: swift, storyboard

I tried to dismiss the keyboard upon tapping the message collection view this way:

```
   let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.didTapBackground))
    self.messagesCollectionView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

@objc private func didTapBackground() {
        print("tapped")
        messageInputBar.inputTextView.resignFirstResponder()
    }


private func configureMessageInputBar() {
        messageInputBar.delegate = self
        
        let button = InputBarButtonItem()
        button.image = UIImage(named: "attach")
        button.setSize(CGSize(width: 36, height: 36), animated: false)
        
        button.onTouchUpInside { (item) in
            self.actionAttachMessage()
        }
        
        messageInputBar.setStackViewItems([button], forStack: .left, animated: false)
        messageInputBar.setLeftStackViewWidthConstant(to: 36, animated: false)
  
        messageInputBar.contentView.backgroundColor = .clear
        messageInputBar.inputTextView.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.5568627451, green: 0.4705882353, blue: 0.9568627451, alpha: 1)
        messageInputBar.inputTextView.layer.borderWidth = 3
        messageInputBar.inputTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 16
        messageInputBar.inputTextView.isImagePasteEnabled = false
     
        messageInputBar.inputTextView.backgroundColor = .clear
        messageInputBar.isTranslucent = true
       
        messageInputBar.inputTextView.textColor = .white
    }
```

package used: https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit

[image: Screenshot of issue]

Comment: You've posted a bunch of code but you haven't provided any details about your issue. What problem exactly are you having with the code you posted? Please don't reply in a comment. Edit your question with relevant details.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.messagesCollectionView.endEditing(true)
```

Comment: Please don't post an answer that only has a single line of code and no explanation. A good answer explains what is wrong with the OP's code and explains how the answer solves the problem.